# Convert ObservableCollection of parent type to child

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting, observablecollection

I have class CheckBoxObject and DeployCheckBoxObject that derived from CheckBoxObject.

i have observable collection of CheckBoxObject and for each element of the collection want to use child properties and functions.

how can i convert the parent collection to child ?

```
public class CheckboxObject : ViewModelBase
{
        public CheckboxObject(object o)
        {
            Object = o;
        }
        public object Object;
        public string Name => Object.ToString();
}

public class DeployCheckBoxObject : CheckboxObject
{
        public DeployCheckBoxObject(object o) : base(o)
        {

        }
        
        public string status { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
        ObservableCollection<DeployCheckBoxObject> items = new ObservableCollection<DeployCheckBoxObject>();

public void populate(someObject) {

  items = someObject.ToObservableCheckboxCollection(); //error

  }

}
```

I also try to call child functions with parent object and get invalid cast error

```
public class Test
{
        ObservableCollection<CheckBoxObject> items = new ObservableCollection<CheckBoxObject>();

  public void populate(someObject) {

   items = someObject.ToObservableCheckboxCollection(); 
   foreach (CheckboxObject cb in CbVendorItems) {
     ((DeployCheckBoxObject)cb).Count = 100; //error
   }
  }

}
```

```
public static ObservableCollection<CheckboxObject> ToObservableCheckboxCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerableList)
        {
            var a = new ObservableCollection<CheckboxObject>();
            if (enumerableList == null) return a;
            foreach (var item in enumerableList)
            {
                a.Add(new CheckboxObject(item));
            }
            return a;
        }
```

how can i access to child methods ?

Comment: where is your definition of `ToObservableCheckBoxCollection`?

Comment: Can you try and provide a [mcve]. The code above references things that don't exist  - e.g. `ToObservableCheckBoxCollection`, `DeployCheckBoxObject.Count`, `CbVendorItems` - and `someObject` doesn't have a type.

Comment: Sounds like an XY Question. Do your really need an `ObservableCollection<DeployCheckBoxObject>`, or do you just want to set a property of `DeployCheckBoxObject` on some elements of an `ObservableCollection<CheckBoxObject>` that may be of type `DeployCheckBoxObject`.

Comment: In fact you can assign an ObservableCollection to an object without errors. https://dotnetfiddle.net/IVXTo5

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that *all* the `CheckBoxObject`s in your collection are actually `DeployCheckBoxObject`s, if so, then why not make your observable collection of the type `DeployCheckBoxObject` instead of `CheckBoxObject`

If you don't know for sure, and some `CheckBoxObject`s may not be a `DeployCheckBoxObject` then you need to check for type safety before casting

```cs
foreach (CheckboxObject cb in CbVendorItems)
{
    if (cb is DeployCheckBoxObject deployCb)
    {
        deployCb.Count = 100;
    }
}
```